# jquery-mobile navigationg back programmatically

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page that a user can arrive at from different parts of the application. Also from this landing page, a user can navigate to another page and come back to this landing page.

Using the default back button functionality would take the user back to that page. In short, I need to keep the url when the user first arrives at this page and than `changePageto` this url.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: to put it more simply keep certain pages out of the history stack. User goes from page A to page B then from page B to page C. Selecting an element on Page C takes the user back to page B. Now hitting back button on page B should go back to page A and not Page C. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your point. Maybe you should use javascript and localStorage mechanism.  When navigating from page A to B set localStorage("source", "a.html"), then on page B init, try this link:

```
window.location.href = ('file:///android_asset/path.../' + localStorage.getItem("source") );
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

`$.mobile.back()`

It even handles the transition reverse direction. From the source :

```
$.mobile.back = function() {
    var nav = window.navigator;

    // if the setting is on and the navigator object is
    // available use the phonegap navigation capability
    if( this.phonegapNavigationEnabled &&
        nav &&
        nav.app &&
        nav.app.backHistory ){
        nav.app.backHistory();
    } else {
        window.history.back();
    }
};
```